# Kafka IHostedService consumer in Kubernetes multiple instances

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, asp.net-core-webapi, kafka-consumer-api

I have an `ASP.NET Core WebAPI` service that runs in `Kubernetes`. That service also hosts a `IHostedService` that is a `Kafka` consumer.
Would there be an issue with the `Kafka` consumer if I configure multiple replicas of the service?
I am asking because multiple instances will consume, process and try to commit the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and try to commit the same message.

This isn't possible. Multiple consumers in a consumer group cannot read the same records, therefore won't try to commit the same offsets